# Invalid conversion from ‘const std::vector<cv::Mat>*’ to ‘std::vector<cv::Mat>*’ in c++14

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When running the following code

RM_Analyzer.h:

```
struct FFeatureCalculationImages
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat>* cf_mat;
    std::vector<cv::Mat>* front_mat;
    std::vector<cv::Mat>* back_mat;
};

class RM_Analyzer
{
private: 
DLL_Mat<std::vector<cv::Mat> > sliding_window_frames;
void setImagesForExtendedFeatureCalculation(FFeatureCalculationImages &imgs) const;
}
```

RM_Analyzer.cpp

```
void RM_Analyzer::setImagesForExtendedFeatureCalculation(FFeatureCalculationImages &imgs) const
{
    imgs.cf_mat=sliding_window_frames[sliding_window_frames.size()-1-k];
    imgs.front_mat=sliding_window_frames.getFrontMat();
    imgs.back_mat=sliding_window_frames.getBackMat();
}
```

DLL_Mat.h

```
template<class T>
class DLLNode
{
public:
    DLLNode<T>* next;
    DLLNode<T>* previous;
    T im;
};


template<class T>
class DLL_Mat
{
private:
    unsigned count;
    DLLNode<T>* front;
    DLLNode<T>* back;

public:
    T* getFrontMat() const;
    T* getBackMat() const;
    unsigned size() const;
    T* operator[](const std::size_t idx);
    const T* operator[](const std::size_t idx) const;
};

template <class T>
inline unsigned DLL_Mat<T>::size() const
{
    return count;
}

template <class T>
T* DLL_Mat<T>::operator[](const std::size_t idx)
{
    if (idx==0)
        return getFrontMat();
    else if (idx==(count-1))
        return getBackMat();
    else if (idx>=size())
        return nullptr;
    else
    {
        std::size_t i=0;
        for (DLLNode<T> *iter=front;i<count;i++,iter=iter->next)
        {
            if (i==idx)
                return &(iter->im);
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}

template <class T>
const T* DLL_Mat<T>::operator[](const std::size_t idx) const
{
    if (idx==0)
        return getFrontMat();
    else if (idx==(count-1))
        return getBackMat();
    else if (idx>=size())
        return nullptr;
    else
    {
        std::size_t i=0;
        for (DLLNode<T> *iter=front;i<count;i++,iter=iter->next)
        {
            if (i==idx)
                return &(iter->im);
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

I have included the operator [] source code for convenience, although the function declarations in DLL_Mat.h and the RM_Analyzer source code are probably enough to find the culprit of the problem.

The compiler seems to be calling a const version of the operator [], 
which in turn causes a conversion error. The error is (Line 3 in RM_Analyzer.cpp):

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const std::vector<cv::Mat>*’ to ‘std::vector<cv::Mat>*’ [-fpermissive]
     imgs.cf_mat=sliding_window_frames[sliding_window_frames.size()-1-k];
```

My explanation:
1) I seem to have made a logical error somewhere since the function setImagesForExtendedFeatureCalculation should obviously be const since I do not change any internal variable in that method
2) The compiler cannot call non-const operator [] since I declared the method  setImagesForExtendedFeatureCalculation as const so sliding_window_frames is treated as const as well
3) I cannot call the const version of the operator [] since the argument (FFeatureCalculationImages) parameters are not declared const (specifically cf_mat, front_mat, back_mat).

This seems to put me in a peculiar position where neither of the operator [] methods is a good fit, yet declaring a `T* operator[] (const size_t idx) const;` is not a possible overload given the two existing methods in DLL_Mat.h.

Any advice on how to evade the invalid conversion error without throwing away the const function declarations? (since I think that would be a bit sloppy to not declare a function as const just because it is convenient for me)

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [mutable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Isn't this a near-minimal reproducible example? I don't need to include the main function if the goal is to create an object (.o) file - which is the step where the compiler is throwing an error.

Comment: Why wouldn't it call the `const` version of the `[]` operator of a `const` class member? As far as the code in any `const` class method is concerned, all class members are `const` in that method. That's what a `const` method means, after all.

Comment: Plenty of functions here that aren't needed to reproduce the problem, I'm sure.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It does call the const version of the operator []. However that fails since the argument to the function setImagesForExtendedFeatureCalculation is not const so the error invalid conversion from const... occurs

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks! Setting sliding_window_frames as mutable in RM_Analyzer.h allowed for the code to compile. I cannot but feel that this is a hack - telling the compiler to "treat all class members as const but just not this one". Although it is a quick and dirty solution that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sliding_window_frames[sliding_window_frames.size()-1-k]`, the compiler does call the const version of `operator[]`. Which returns a pointer to `const std::vector<cv::Mat>`. But then you are trying to assign that pointer to `imgs.cf_mat`, which is a pointer to *non-const* `std::vector<cv::Mat>`. This violates const correctness, and so the compiler rightfully complains.

You have a function that can be called on a const instance of the object, trying to hand out mutable pointers to internals of that object. Either that function shouldn't have been declared `const`, or it should be handing out const pointers, or the internals it exposes should be marked `mutable`.

Comment: Assuming that the function should be declared const - How would I hand out const pointers?

Comment: E.g. you could declare `FFeatureCalculationImages` members to be `const std::vector<cv::Mat>*`

Answer (score -1):

Both operator[] methods have same signature (return type is not part of signature; edit: they have different signature because of constness of this pointer) therefore you can't select which method you want to call. Having two identical methods doing same thing but one is returning const value isn't right solution: You can always cast to const but you cant otherway, therefore you should remove method returning const value.

Edit:
Field of const object have also const modifier, so operator[] with const this pointer are called (which return const pointer).

P. S. Operator[] takes const argument in header but non-const argument in definition; size() should return std::size_t.

Comment: Fixed the PS first about the non-const argument. Thanks! Pasted the code here at different times; it should, of course, be const

Comment: It is too possible to overload member functions on `const` qualifier of the function; effectively, on constness of `this` pointer. Such overloads are commonplace. See e.g. [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)